# Remove selected children from parent TableView

Tags: android

I have a TableView that I programmaticly add in rows to using a simple loop like the follows

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());       
for (int i = 0; i < dataList.size(); ++i)
{
    DataEntry dataEntry = dataList.valueAt(i);
    // Add the row
    TableRow row = (TableRow)inflater.inflate(R.layout.data_row, _table, false);            
    _table.addView(row);
    row.setTag("dataRow");

    // Code that looks up the 'column' views and sets their value to the dataEntry
}
```

This is working great and populates the list just fine. But when I am changing data sets I want to clear out all the added rows **except** the header (first) row and then add in a new set of rows (ie run the code above). So I have this little bit of code:

```
final int childCount = _table.getChildCount();
for (int i = 1; i < childCount; ++i)
{
    View view = _table.getChildAt(i);
    _table.removeView(view);
}
```

This is the most simple version of this loop I could do. I was originally checking for null views because they showed up on resuming the task. I would then check to see if the tag for the view was == "dataRow" and only remove the data rows. But this all gives me the same result. It will skip the header (I am starting at 1 instead of 0) and remove the next row and then every other row from there on down. If I run this loop enough times it Will clear the list but adding a while(_table.getChildCount()>1) just seems like I am clearly just doing this wrong. _table.removeAllChildren() will not work as the header is then removed as well (And it likes to rip apart view hierarchies which is also not what I want done).

I am just not seeing what it is I am doing wrong. I am hoping a second (or second hundred) set of eyes may see the flaw in my thinking.

Answer (score 0):

And I figured it out around 4min after I asked this.

I am looping through the children and removing them. The parent is then sliding all of the entries down. Changing the for loop to the following works (and is ironicly turning this for loop into a while (>1) I thought seemed like a bad idea.

```
for (int i = 1; i < childCount; ++i)
    _table.removeView(_table.getChildAt(1));
```

This makes sense now that I look at it.. I should probably remove from the bottom up for a bit cleaner code and should have remembered this is the proper way to remove items from a linked list which may very well be what the children list is.